# Slow SQL Queries against a table causing blocking

Tags: sql, performance, blocking

What could be possible reasons on why all statements executing against a table would run extremely slowly causing blocking.  No particular query was the culprit.  At some point whatever was causing it ended and all statements started executing normal and all blocking was cleared up.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A corrupt index could cause the issue.  If there are indexes, you can recreate them.  If you're using table replication, if the replication is out of sync, this can cause slow queries especially if the tables handle a high volume of transactions.  If you haven't done so, you may want to log the slow queries as even queries that take .5 seconds can quickly cause a bottleneck on high-traffic systems.  Those are my "surface" thoughts.  Other considerations such as disk space, RAM, disk integrity, etc. also come to mind.  You may want to consider checking your system logs to see if anything shows up there during the time you experienced the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  The head of the blocking chain would be running but taking minutes when usually would run in seconds.  When it completed the next in line behaved the same.  We do replicate the table but from what I can tell it was not having any issues. The server has 256 GB of memory, the database is 400 GB with a max memory for the instance at 128 GB.  The server has 2 2.9Ghz -8 core processors hyper threaded.

Comment: I do not think it is a disk issue and since it seems to have been related to one particular table I was thinking it was not a server resource.  There was nothing in the log that indicated an issue.

Comment: Did you identify the head blocker? what was it waiting on? Or were there no waits reported? You might want to focus on that head blocker query and work out of there are any stale statistics, stale plan or parameter sniffing issues.

Comment: I think I can rule out parameter sniffing because both ad_hoc and parameterized queries were having this issue, also a lot of different statements were having the same issue.  I killed a few that were not doing anything that would cause issues.  I also did an update stats on the table with the default sample size which would invalidate all plans.  After 10 or 15 minutes I was still having issues, I remembered we usually update stats nightly with sample size 100% because of our skewed data.

Comment: The table has 10 million records and since we update stats nightly with 100% sample, in my mind it seems hard to believe that the stats were out of date in 8 hours tops.  It might be true, I was thinking along the same lines as you Nick but I have no way to prove it.

Comment: The next thing I did was update stats with sample size 100.  I am not sure but maybe after all the queries on the runnable queue cleared up the issue went away.  It was weird because the issue just cleared up after say 15 minutes or so.  The only other thing that I did was killed some sleeping commands another DBA had to the Production environment.